# Firebase and Stripe: Storing users credit card information

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, stripe-payments

I am programming an iOS application that needs to store users credit card information for them to change and also so that payments can happen without entering the card in each time.

I'm using Firebase as my database and Stripe to allow purchases to go through. Heroku handles all of the stripe tokens.

Right now, I have it so that the user has to keep entering a card in each time they want to make a payment, but I would like to store this information securely so that they don't have to do this.

Can I store it on Firebase? Is there an easier safe way to store credit card information for each user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I store it on Firebase?

Sure, if you are ready for [PCI compliance](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org).

Your best option is to setup [subscriptions](https://stripe.com/docs/subscriptions/quickstart) to manage monthly subscriptions or for in app purchases see the [IOS](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios) API for Stripe.